# How to include Unit and Integration test in Sonar Code Coverage

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco, cobertura, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am using below commands to build my maven code.

Compile-

```
-DargLine="-DDB_SERVER=localhost -DDB_PORT=5432 -DDB_NAME=sample -DDB_USER=sample -DDB_PASSWORD=sample -DDB_MAX_POOL=10" -Dcom.sample.redis=false clean compiler:compile
```

Unit-Test Analysis-

```
DargLine=-DDB_SERVER=localhost -DDB_PORT=1234 -DDB_NAME=sample -DDB_USER=sample -DDB_PASSWORD=sample -DDB_MAX_POOL=10 -Dcom.sample.redis=false -Dcobertura:cobertura-integration-test -Dcobertura.aggregate=false -Dcobertura.report.format=xml integration-test test
```

And using below sonar properties to capture xml to publish in sonar.

```
sonar.projectKey=sample
sonar.projectName=sample
sonar.projectVersion=$PipelineId
sonar.modules=admin,client-api,common,om,serviceproviders
sonar.cobertura.reportPath=target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml
sonar.sources=.
sonar.skipPackageDesign=true
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Being Multi module the code coverage is showing only 9.4%. Am I missing anything. I don't see any error logs as well.How can I achieve the same using coverage tool like Jacoco.

SonarQube - `Version 5.1.1 - LGPL v3`

Comment: The current version is 6.4 and the current LTS is 5.6.6. You're not likely to find a lot of help for versions < those.

Answer (score 0):

Maven has a lifecycle [Maven Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) where each of the targets includes the ones before it.  e.g. "test" includes "compile", "integration-test" includes "test", etc.  You generally need to only include the target at the tip of the lifecycle.  e.g. "mvn test" means (compile AND run the tests).

I'm thinking you want to run the "mvn verify" goal, which is compile, run tests and integration tests, and then run verifications (coverage checks, etc).  Cobertura has a plugin that should integrate with maven and tap into various goals to run its pieces at appropriate times.  I'm guessing you are messing up cobertura by having multiple targets and trying to break it into pieces - i.e. overwriting the instrumentation or something.

Similarly, you might find using jacoco easier than cobertura.  It hides the instrumentation, and integrates pretty seemlessly with maven.

Good luck.

Comment: How can I achieve the same using Jacoco coverage tool?